# Is it possible to render custom extension without include in backend in template module of TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I am newer in typo3.
I don't know how it is do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, your question is a little bit too short.

Extending TYPO3 will mostly realized with help of an UserFunc. And yes, extbase and piBase are UserFunc's, too. You want to implement your own PHP based solution? Implement it with help of an UserFunc:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

As you see I have posted a link to the TypoScript reference of TYPO3. As TypoScript have to be included somehow (mainly in the Template Module) there are IMO only 2 further ways to add TypoScript without TS backend module:

`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScript();`

Else, you can create a file named `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript` in root of your extension. Every TypoScript in there will be added automatically.

The official way says: Create file `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php` and register your TypoScript as follows:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    'your_ext_key',
    'Configuration/TypoScript',
    'A cool title for TS backend module'
);
```

Nice greetings

Stefan

Comment: It's really helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.
You should give more information about:

- what have you tried?
- what is your current situation?
- what do you want to achieve?

**I assume:**
you want some output of an extension, which you wrote yourself.

the mechanism in TYPO3 for this are `plugins`. Those can be inserted as content elements in a page. The configuration, what to display can be done with `TypoScript`, which can be page specific. Or you enable the editors to configure the output with data in the plugin.

There are multiple possibilities to create plugins. you may start the documentations here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FrontendPlugin/Index.html or search a tutorial regarding "developing plugins for TYPO3".

For beginners it might be easy to use the [ExtensionBuilder](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder), an Extension to build extensions. It will give you the frame for your code to integrate in TYPO3.